# How to add module with multiple resources to WildFly using CLI

Tags: server, module, jboss, command-line-interface, wildfly

I've found this example of how to add a module:

```
module add --name=org.postgres --resources=postgresql-42.2.5.jar --dependencies=javax.api,javax.transaction.api
```

This works, but how do I specify multiples .jar files? I tried separating the file paths with commas, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the `--resource-delimiter=,` command line option:

```
module add --name=org.blah --resource-delimiter=, --resources=${user.home}/some.jar,${user.home}/someother.jar --dependencies=javax.api,javax.transaction.api
```

Answer (score 1):

As per redHat documentation colon(:) or semicolon(;) can be used based on operating system

For linux - :. Example, --resources=path-to-jar:path-to-another-jar

For Windows - ;. Example, --resources=path-to-jar;path-to-another-jar

It worked for me on wildly 23

```
module add --name=commonlib --resources=abc.jar;xyz.jar --dependencies=javax.api,javax.transaction.api
```

Link - https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.1/html/development_guide/class_loading_and_modules